# Circular Inclusion and Inheritence with Forward Declarations Leads to C2504 base class undefined

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, composition, circular-dependency

I am getting a C2504 compilation error in PlayerController.h saying that my base class (Updateable) is undefined. I have searched for several hours for a solution to a circular inclusion with inheritance problem and their solutions are to remove the circular inclusions and jsut use a forward declaration. As far as I understand, this works if no methods from the forward declared class are called. However, in my program my Updateables class calls a method on its member inherited gameObject object and the GameObjects also call methods on their member Updateables. Because of this, Updateables need to include GameObject.h and GameObjects need to include Updateables.h. This leads to a C2504 in PlayerController.h saying that the base class Updateable can not be found.

Here are my relevant classes:

Component.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Vector3.h"

class GameObject;

class Component {
public:
    GameObject* gameObject = nullptr;

    Component();
};
```

Component.cpp

```
#include "Component.h"

Component::Component() {}
```

Updateable.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Component.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

class GameObject;

class Updateable : public Component {

public:
    ~Updateable();
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

Updateable.cpp

```
#include "Updateable.h"

Updateable::~Updateable() { 

    if (gameObject) {
        gameObject->removeUpdateable(this);
    }
}
```

GameObject.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Updateable.h"
#include "GameManager.h"

class Updateable;

class GameObject {

public:

    GameObject();
    ~GameObject();

    void runUpdateables();
    void addUpdateable(Updateable* updateable);
    void removeUpdateable(Updateable* updateable);

private:
     vector<Updateable*> updateables;
};
```

GameObject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"

GameObject::GameObject() {

    updateables = vector<Updateable*>();
    GameManager::addGameObject(this);
}

GameObject::~GameObject() {

    GameManager::removeGameObject(this);
}

void GameObject::runUpdateables() {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < updateables.size(); i++) {
        updateables[i]->update();
    }
}

void GameObject::addUpdateable(Updateable* updateable) {

    updateables.push_back(updateable);
    updateable->gameObject = this;
}

void GameObject::removeUpdateable(Updateable* updateable) {

    auto it = find(updateables.begin(), updateables.end(), updateable);
    if (it != updateables.end()) {
        updateables.erase(it);
    }
}
```

PlayerController.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Updateable.h"
//#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Input.h"

class Updateable;

class PlayerController : public Updateable {

public:

    float speed = 5.0f;

    void update();
};
```

PlayerController.cpp

```
#include "PlayerController.h"

void PlayerController::update() {

    float x = 0;

    if (Input::getKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        x = -speed;
    }

    if (Input::getKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        x = speed;
    }

    cout << x << endl;

    gameObject->getRigidBody()->velocity.x = x;
    //yes this is a method in GameObject that I removed from this post
    //because it would take up more space, rigidbody.h does not create
    //a circular dependency
}
```

GameManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"
#include "PlayerController.h"

class GameManager {

public:

    static void init();
    static void addGameObject(GameObject* go);
    static void removeGameObject(GameObject* go);

    static void onFrame();

private:
    static vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
    static GameObject* box;
```

GameManager.cpp

```
#include "GameManager.h"

vector<GameObject*> GameManager::gameObjects;
GameObject* GameManager::box;

void GameManager::init() {

    gameObjects = vector<GameObject*>();

    box = new GameObject();
    box->addUpdateable(new PlayerController());
}

void GameManager::addGameObject(GameObject* go) {
    gameObjects.push_back(go);
}

void GameManager::removeGameObject(GameObject* go) {

    auto it = find(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), go);
    if (it != gameObjects.end()) {
        gameObjects.erase(it);
    }
}

void GameManager::onFrame() {

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        gameObjects[i]->runUpdateables();
    }
}
```

Here is the exact error message: Error  C2504   'Updateable': base class undefined  Basic Platformer    c:\users\default.sixcore-pc\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\basic platformer\basic platformer\playercontroller.h  9

Comment: Why do you forward declare `PlayerController` in `Updateable`?

Comment: You do use `Component`, you use it in `Updatable` so you need to define its constructor.

Comment: You need to include the necessary header files in the *source* files, where the object are used. In the header files with proper forward declaration you don't need to include any header files at all.

Comment: @RickAstley I accidentally left it in there while trying to find a solution, I didn't expect it to work and it didn't

Comment: @Galik I add my component.cpp, it had a constructor, but nothing was in it so I didn't add it originally

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tried moving the include for Updateable in PlayerController.h to the .cpp but it produces the error 3 times

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error message?

Comment: @Galik I added the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of your files have both `#include "Class.h"` and `class Class;` declarations. You never need both; use one or the other.

A definition of a class `X` must be visible when:

- accessing the members of `X`
- creating an object of type `X`
- defining a class derived from `X`
- using `X` as a template argument to a template which requires the corresponding template parameter to be a complete type (such as what standard library containers require of their element type). Note that this applies when using `X`, not `X*`.

In other cases (such as creating a pointer to `X` or declaring a function taking of returning `X`), a non-defining declaration (`class X;`) is enough.

Using these rules (plus moving function bodies from headers to source files when necessary), you can solve any circular dependency issues.

---

To directly address your files as presented:

- `Updateable.h` does not need to `#include "GameObject.h"`. It doesn't even need the forward declaration of `GameObject`.
- `GameObject.h` doesn't need any of the two `#include`s in it.
- `GameManager.h` doesn't need any `#include`s. It needs a declaration of `class GameObject;` though.

Answer (score 0):

Descendant class must know the full definition of the base class. Forward declaration is not enough and useless.

Comment: The full definition is only needed when a class is *instantiated*, or when accessing members. Just for the inheritance all one need is the declared symbol.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am afraid that's not true. Defining a derived class needs the definition of all of its base classes; it couldn't figure out the layour & size otherwise.

Comment: @Angew If the full definition is available when the class is instantiated (for example by including all needed header files) then in the header file one could do `class A; class B : public A { ... };` without the need to explicitly include a header file for the class `A`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's just [not true](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d737bc011070993). N4659, [class.derived] 13/2: "A *class-or-decltype* shall denote a class type **that is not an incompletely defined class** (Clause 12). The class
denoted by the *class-or-decltype* of a *base-specifier* is called a *direct base class* for the class being defined." (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @Angew I admit defeat, even though in my own testing (using multiple header files and only forward declarations) it worked fine.

Comment: It may work if you included the header of the base class before the header of the descendant. Probably it worked because of a luckily ordered headers.